# How can I run a AngularJS project without Gruntjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, eclipse, gruntjs

I want to run my AngularJS project without Gruntjs.

Is it possible? If possible, please let me know the procedure.

Running on **windows** machine. Already installed `node.js` and `eclipse mars 4.5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just open index.html in browser.**

To have safe url. It's better, of course, to install some static server like http-server and run it from the folder:

```
npm install http-server
http-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) -> Copy your app to the wamp/www directory - > go to localhost/yourprojectname in your browser and open your app BAM!

Or you could just open your app by clicking on your index.html though be warned if you are using any form of routing its not gona work. better to setup a localhost server either using node as STEVER suggested or any other server of your choice